# Reading a sharepoint list in C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint-list

I'd like to read a list on a project server site
So I create a list that which called GetUrl
And I just like to read the title of this list
So I write this piece of code:

```
`string strUrl = "http://site-2016-02:1000/PWA/";
            using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(strUrl))
            {
                using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList list = oWeb.Lists["GetUrl"];

                    foreach (SPField field in list.Fields)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(field.Title);
                    }
                }
            }
```

`but I get the following error:
Additional information: The Web application at http://sfd-2013-02:1000/PWA/ could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.

I don't understand why when I click on the url the project site is showed
So any idea of what I'm doing wrong?
Is there another solution to be able to read a sharepoint list?

Thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

SPSite represents a Site Collection and most likely PWA is a subsite.

```
string strUrl = "http://site-2016-02:1000";
        using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(strUrl))
        {
            using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.RootWeb.OpenWeb("PWA"))
```

or

```
string strUrl = "http://site-2016-02:1000";
        using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(strUrl))
        {
            using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.RootWeb.Webs["PWA"])
```